# C# XML LINQ searching

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a XML file like this:

```
  <SoftwareComponent schemaVersion="1.0" packageID="Y75WC" releaseID="Y75WC" hashMD5="a190fdfa292276288df38507ea551a3b" path="FOLDER04650736M/1/OptiPlex_3050_1.7.9.exe" dateTime="2017-12-05T05:34:30+00:00" releaseDate="décembre 05, 2017" vendorVersion="1.7.9" dellVersion="1.7.9" packageType="LWXP" identifier="532f5a9e-c087-4499-b40c-cf7921ee06d3" rebootRequired="true">
<Name>
  <Display lang="en"><![CDATA[Dell OptiPlex 3050 System BIOS,1.7.9]]></Display>
</Name>
<ComponentType value="BIOS">
  <Display lang="en"><![CDATA[BIOS]]></Display>
</ComponentType>
<Description>
  <Display lang="en"><![CDATA[This package provides the Dell System BIOS update and is supported on Dell OptiPlex 3050 Tower, OptiPlex 3050 Small Form Factor and OptiPlex 3050 Micro for Windows Operation System.]]></Display>
</Description>
<LUCategory value="NONE">
  <Display lang="en"><![CDATA[None]]></Display>
</LUCategory>
<Category value="BI">
  <Display lang="en"><![CDATA[FlashBIOS Updates]]></Display>
</Category>
<SupportedDevices>
  <Device componentID="159" embedded="0">
    <Display lang="en"><![CDATA[OptiPlex 3050 System BIOS]]></Display>
  </Device>
</SupportedDevices>
<SupportedSystems>
  <Brand key="1" prefix="OP">
    <Display lang="en"><![CDATA[Optiplex]]></Display>
    <Model systemID="07A3">
      <Display lang="en"><![CDATA[3050]]></Display>
    </Model>
  </Brand>
</SupportedSystems>
<ImportantInfo URL="http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=Y75WC" />
<Criticality value="2">
  <Display lang="en"><![CDATA[Urgent-Dell highly recommends applying this update as soon as possible. The update contains changes to improve the reliability and availability of your Dell system.]]></Display>
</Criticality>
```

There are multiple SoftwareComponent Elements inside.

I tried to get some attributes of SoftwareComponent ( dellVersion, hashMD5) based on descendants Elements ( ComponentType value, SupportedSystems->Device->Display value, Criticality value) but all my tests were not good.

See my actual code, I can get all the value in the XML file only:

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("catalog.xml");
        var els = from el in doc.Root.Elements("SoftwareComponent")
                      select new
                      {
                          dellVersion = (string)el.Attribute("dellVersion"),
                          hashMD5 = (string)el.Attribute("hashMD5"),
                          path = (string)el.Attribute("path"),

                      };

        foreach (var el in els)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("dell BIOS: {0}, MD5: {1}, path: {2}", el.dellVersion, el.hashMD5, el.path);
        }
```

Somebody can show me how to proceed please ?

Thanks

Comment: You could use HtmlAgilityPack on that. They have pretty good samples on their website.

Comment: Replace Elements() with Descendants.  You did post enough of your xml be sure but I think I'm correct.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your XML document is missing a `</SoftwareComponent>` end tag. Maybe you didn't copy the contents OK here.

Then, `SoftwareComponent` is actually the root in your document, so you would need code like:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("catalog.xml");

var el = new
{
    dellVersion = (string)doc.Root.Attribute("dellVersion"),
    hashMD5 = (string)doc.Root.Attribute("hashMD5"),
    path = (string)doc.Root.Attribute("path"),
};

Console.WriteLine("dell BIOS: {0}, MD5: {1}, path: {2}", el.dellVersion, el.hashMD5, el.path);
```

Your code would work OK as-is if the XML would have the format:

```
<Root>
    <SoftwareComponent schemaVersion="1.0" packageID="Y75WC" releaseID="Y75WC" hashMD5="a190fdfa292276288df38507ea551a3b" path="FOLDER04650736M/1/OptiPlex_3050_1.7.9.exe" dateTime="2017-12-05T05:34:30+00:00" releaseDate="décembre 05, 2017" vendorVersion="1.7.9" dellVersion="1.7.9" packageType="LWXP" identifier="532f5a9e-c087-4499-b40c-cf7921ee06d3" rebootRequired="true">
    </SoftwareComponent>
</Root>
```

XML documents can only have one root node, so you can't have multiple `SoftwareComponent` as root as you seem to imply.

---

If you want to get, for example, ComponentType value, you can do:

```
componentTypeValue = (string)el.Descendants("ComponentType").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("value")
```

I would actually change the query into a `foreach` and check that `FirstOrDefault` result for null.